# SQLite disk I/O error (3850)

Tags: sqlite, errors

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the I/O Error:

```
$sqlite3 db.sqlite < data.sql 
(3850) disk I/O error
Error: near line 2: disk I/O error
(3850) disk I/O error
Error: near line 3: disk I/O error
(3850) disk I/O error
Error: near line 5: disk I/O error
(3850) disk I/O error
Error: near line 8: disk I/O error
(3850) disk I/O error
Error: near line 9: disk I/O error
```

---

See the contents of data.sql below

```
$ less data.sql
.log stderr 
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "temp_user_C560B60C-B690-FF4A-8D35-C9A6D4EE2A6B_purchases" (
  "product_id" varchar(36) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "temp_user_C560B60C-B690-FF4A-8D35-C9A6D4EE2A6B_purchases" VALUES ('C6E07AA2-5B01-11E4-9116-00166E0083A1');
INSERT INTO "temp_user_C560B60C-B690-FF4A-8D35-C9A6D4EE2A6B_purchases" VALUES ('C6E07AA2-5B01-11E4-9116-00166E0083AA');
END TRANSACTION;
```

I already saw this issue: [disk I/O error in SQLite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44156/disk-i-o-error-in-sqlite)
but my issue generates a different error code after I inserted `.log stderr` at the top of the data.sql file and I am not using Virtualbox - I am not sure if the host is using another form of virtualisation.

Comment: Is `db.sqlite` in the current working directory? Does `sqlite3 db.sqlite` by itself on the command-line give any errors?

Comment: Looks like a probably write permission issue on the file `db.sqlite` anyway. Do you have write permission on it? Also, check the user hasn't exceeded its Unix quota. (The 3850 error code is present in the sqlite test suite, and tests for file access)

Answer (score 4):

So our sysadmin just told me:
`"we use VMWare virtualization, and the system is fully optimized as a VM (virtio, etc.).You are trying to do the read and the write to an NFS mounted disk (my home directory)"`
I tried the command in `/tmp` and it worked there.

Comment: I had the same problem. Copying the file to any other mounted filesystem worked, but any copy on the original filesystem failed. So I presume that sqlite did some strange filesystem-level locking. ***Rebooting solved the issue.***